# Why didn't Kaminoians inform Obi-Wan that Count Dooku took over with ordering the clone army?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

in the Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones movie we can See that Count Dooku took over with ordering the clone army, did he ask for the clone Army to have the biochip that would turn against the Jedi's. So my Question is Why didnt Kaminoians inform Obi-Wan of this?

Comment: They thought Obi-Wan was allied with Dooku and newer went into details?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi How do u know?

Comment: Just a guess ) (see question mark)

Comment: Consider that the Kaminoans received very little communication ("We were beginning to wonder if you weren't coming"). Maybe they just kept operating under what Sifo-Dyas had told them. It's possible Dooku interacted with them very little and, when he did, they just assumed he was an apprentice or some other Jedi.

Comment: I guess for about the same reason Jango Fett is able to use sonic weaponry in space, or one planet manages to be South of another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Kaminoans didn't know that the Jedi didn't know about it.**

Basically, Sidious and Dooku's manipulations meant that, prior to Obi-Wan's meeting with Taun We and Lama Su on Kamino, both the Jedi and the Kaminoans were completely in the dark about the situation:

- The Jedi had no idea the Clone Army even existed; Jedi Master Sifo-Dyas had ordered it of his own volition, and was then murdered so that the Sith could hijack the project without the Jedi finding out about it
- The Kaminoans had no idea that Sidious and Dooku were Sith; they believed they were Jedi working at the behest of the Council. They therefore had no reason to believe that the Jedi didn't know about the modifications to the clones' chips, let alone that they didn't know about the project at all. As far as they knew, the Jedi Council had signed off on everything.

Ironically, if Obi-Wan had admitted that the Jedi had known nothing about the Clone Army, instead of bluffing to gain access to the facility, that almost certainly would have raised alarm bells: "Then who have we been speaking to for the past ten years?!" Instead, his bluff reinforced the Kaminoans' belief that the Jedi knew everything about the project, up to and including the implanting of Order 66.

Comment: but in clone wars series, isn't there an implication that at least Lama Su knew she was dealing w/ Sith?

Comment: I haven't watched much of *The Clone Wars*, so maybe.

Comment: @F1Krazy In the Conspiracy arc Lama Su is just enacting the orders of the person who she believes is in charge. To the best of my memory she isn't fully aware that he is a Sith (despite the evil hood). Her evil portrayal to the audience can mostly be explained by the fact that she believes clones to be expendable.